# Sharepoint 2010 Get Group ID

Tags: sharepoint-2010, schema

How do I get the ID of a custom group? It doesn't seem to be in the group edit menu.

I need to know in order to restrict the people picker in my schema to a certain group.

```
<Field ID="{7B0BC328-5F1F-4BD1-8D8B-4F01F815734F}" Name="Assigned To" DisplayName="Assigned To" Type="User" Group="" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PowerShell you should be able to do something like this from the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell on the server:

```
$siteCollection = Get-SPSite "http://<my_site_collection>"
$siteCollection.RootWeb.Groups | Format-Table -Property Name, ID
```